# How can I pin (affix) this bootstrap div/ element to the top of the page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've been struggling to understand how to affix the jumbotron div in this bootstrap example. I want to keep the affix-top navigation div but also I would like the same effect to take place for the jumbotron.

Any ideas?

Here's the example - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=enable-affix-via-data-attribute

The div I'd like to affix is here:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Bootstrap Affix</h1>
</div>
```

I believe that I have to make CSS that also defines the behavior of the jumbotron or am I wrong with that?

Answer (score -1):

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix
This should help you out ;) you need an extra import